# How to use Point and Spot Lights With Mesh instancing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader, lighting

I've been Experimenting with GPU Instancing to draw **1,60,000 Meshes** and Unity's Graphics API has some really Good Functions to achieve this.
 I am currently using **Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced** and I get the Meshes on the Screen, However, these Instanced Meshes only react to Directional Light, and not to Point/Sport lights. Is this a Limitation that cannot be overcome or am I missing Something here?

I am currently using an Orthographic Camera with Forward Rendering , and Unity's Standard Shader for the material. If It helps I am trying to make a Simple Rimworld like game.

**With Directional Light**
[image: With Directional Light]

**With Point/Spot Lights**
[image: With Point/Spot Lights]

Comment: Is `Enable Instancing` activated in your material(s)?

Comment: yes! I've enabled it in the material.